# npm run poststop script on ctrl+c

Tags: mongodb, yarnpkg, npm-scripts, sigterm

My `package.json` scripts section looks like this.

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "mongod",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=prod node server.js",
  "poststop": "mongo admin --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'",
  "predev": "mongod",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon server.js"
},
```

I use pre- and post hooks to start `mongod` before starting my server. I then kill my server using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Unfortunately, this doesn't execute the `poststop` script. As a result, calling `npm/yarn start/dev` for the second time throws an error and aborts because `mongod` is already running.

> Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory,
>   terminating

Can I somehow call `poststop` on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

Comment: `poststop` is specific to `mongod`, correct?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter It’s been a while, but IIRC I made that up. Call it whatever you like.

Answer (score 4):

You need to trap the `SIGINT` signal and return a success exit code (0) instead

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "mongod",
  "start": "trap 'exit 0' SIGINT; NODE_ENV=prod node server.js",
  "poststop": "mongo admin --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'",
  "predev": "mongod",
  "dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon server.js"
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't `"poststart"` here to be `"poststop"`?

Comment: hmm this does not seem to work for me, it would just exit and not run the post call. Any suggestions?